# Built in webcam not working properly on Lenovo laptop

Tags: lenovo, webcam

I have a new Lenovo IdeaPad S340 laptop. I am trying to use the built in webcam, but all I get is a dark red window.  I have tried using Cheese and guvcview, but all I see is the dark red. If I hold my hand over the cam, the window goes black, so it does appear to be sensitive to light, but otherwise nothing.  I am running kubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the exact same problem with my Lenovo IdeaPad S340.

It turns out there is actually a built in webcam cover (very well disguised)
Just above the webcam there is a tiny slider which if you move to the right removes the cover and your webcam should work!

Thanks!

Comment: hahaha same problem to me! i laughed a lot when i discovered the webcam cover =P first i blamed the ubuntu drivers till i found this